# In Git for Windows 2.42 / Git Extensions for Windows 4.2.0, how can we disable the Git CLI stdin wrapper?

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash, git-extensions, ssh-agent

I am using Git and Git Extensions for Windows for version control. A part of my workflow is that I open the Git bash **from within Git Extensions** to work on the command line. One of the commands I often use in the Git bash is `ssh-add`, because the remote repositories are available via SSH at most.

This has worked until today without any problems. If I did `ssd-add <my-key-id>`, I was asked for the passphrase for the key **directly in Git bash**.

In today's morning, I have been offered an update of Git extensions for Windows, namely to version 4.2.0, and an update of Git for Windows, namely to 2.42., and I was stupid enough to take these offers.

The result is that I can't reach the remote repositories any more: Following an `ssh-add` command, I am no longer asked for the passphrase in the Git bash; **instead, a GUI dialog opens,** consisting of a text field where I can enter the passphrase, titled "Git Extensions - git CLI stdin wrapper". The problem now is that **this git CLI stdin wrapper does not process my passphrase correctly;** probably it's due to the fact that the passphrase contains all sorts of special characters, including German Umlauts. Anyway, I can't unlock the needed SSH keys any more.

How can I stop this madness? Is it possible to disable that git CLI stdin wrapper so that I can enter the passphrase at the command line again?

It seems that I probably could solve the problem by using other SSH binaries (`ssh-add`, `ssh` and so on), but I don't want to do that. There is absolutely no need for that git CLI stdin wrapper (entering the passphrase directly in Git bash has always worked), and it would be stupid to use another SSH client (the one bundled with Git has always worked reliably as well, and I have put some non-negligible work into its secure configuration).

I am also aware that I could probably solve the problem by opening the Git bash on its own instead of from within Git Extensions. However, this would destroy my current workflow for non-obvious reasons that I don't want to explain here; it would be a very annoying emergency solution.

Furthermore, it is absolutely clear that I won't change my SSH passphrases just because that totally superfluous GUI stdin wrapper passes them along in an incorrect way.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish

Comment: Thanks for the link, and +1, but I can't imagine why the Git Extension for Windows and the Git for Windows developers should have any interest in acting like that ...

Comment: Change introducing bad behavior for you https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/11199 The reason is described in https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/11182 (to better handle password managers). I don't know if there is a workaround using env vars 

Comment: Try set SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE  to value “never”. See https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-add.1

Comment: @Philippe Thank you very much, and +1. I wouldn't have expected that the Git for Windows / Git bash system is compatible to the Linux / BSD variants at that level. That tip was a life saver! If you make your comment an answer, I'll happily accept it. It has solved the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE to value “never” so that it never use the program defined in SSH_ASKPASS (filled by GitExtensions).
See https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-add.1

The reason of the change that introduces the regression on your work flow:

Change introducing bad behavior for you https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/11199 The reason is described in https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/11182 (to better handle password managers)

Comment: Thanks again, +1 and accepted of course. Regarding the bug report, you have convinced me. However, in that special case, I am afraid that I'll be asked to provide the passphrase so that the developers can reproduce the problem. Unfortunately, I can't do that, and right now, I don't have the time to search for other passphrases that raise the same problem (although I believe that it wouldn't take long to find one). Hence, I'll probably report the bug, but I can't provide a passphrase to reproduce the problem. We'll see if that will become a good or a bad experience :-)

Answer (score 1):

As an intermediate solution, you can rename or delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\GitExtSshAskPass.exe`. If it is not present at the expected location, and no `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable is set, then the password will be asked inline.

Note that this applies to all places where `git` asks for a password. However, this is identical to the previous (4.1) behavior, since `SSH_ASKPASS` would only be used in the absence of a console or presence of an input pipe.

Comment: Thank you very much, and upvoted. However, I'll probably give the answer to Philippe (if he makes his comment an answer), because his solution is slightly cleaner in that it does not require to manipulate program directories. Just setting an environment variable that is officially documented is a very elegant and safe solution to the problem :-)

Comment: While cleaner, the down side of setting the environment variable is that it has to be done for every session. Because the system-stored environment variable is overwritten when generating the environment for the shell. That's why I offered a solution that only has to be done once.

P.S. Even if you prefer to use the shell (which could be made an option), the real bug here is in `GitExtSshAskPass`. It should absolutely handle any Unicode character. You should post an issue, giving some hint as to the specific characters that aren't working.

Comment: I don't need to set the environment variable each time because I have put it in `.bashrc`. That way, it is set automatically each time I start Git bash, whether or not from within Git Extensions. Regarding the bug location, you are right of course; However, I have already wasted too much time with bug reports nobody ever took care of. Although this was with other projects, it has made me unwilling to invest more time in bug reports in general.

Comment: Thank you very much for participating in the bug report and for your very helpful suggestions to debug the issue. For everybody else, the bug report (including a working solution) is here: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/11379

Answer (score 1):

It always puzzled me why users come and complain here instead of raising issues to the dev team directly. You can report the issue directly from Git Extensions:
[image]

...or via GitHub at https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues.

Comment: In general, you are right, and therefore I'll be generous and consider your suggestion an answer and upvote it. However, you underestimate the frustration that accumulates over the years if you put a lot of time in many bug reports just to see that nobody cares about them. I am personally affected by such frustration and wish I would have played with the kids instead of wasting my time that way. Hence, for me, bug reports have become the very last resort in case of extreme emergency.

Comment: @Binarus I'm not the community, I'm a GitExtensions dev and I completely agree that you would have been a quicker answer if you have opened an issue. Lucky you that I sometimes wast my time having a look at git questions (when I don't waste my time developing GitExtensions) instead of playing with my kid. I don't know who waste more time trying to help others...

Comment: OK, you have convinced me, see https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/11379 Looking forward to whether or not it was a waste of time :-) (admitting that it will be difficult to reproduce the problem given that I can't provide my actual passphrases that raise the problem; see also my comment to your answer)

Comment: OK, you were right. The reactions to my bug report were extremely satisfying. This is true with respect to the quality of the suggestions and replies as well as the time they needed to provide the further questions, suggestions and even a working fix. I wouldn't have expected that, given my bad experiences with other projects in the past. Lesson learned - each project has its own culture, and I'll report bugs again from now on, at least to projects that haven't disappointed me on that front yet.

Comment: I glad to hear it. It's much easier for us to react and deal with bugs and issues when those submitted directly to us.